# Условие для матрицы в виде таблицы футбольных матчей. С++

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы

Таблица футбольного чемпионата задана квадратной матрицей порядка , в которой все элементы, принадлежащие главной диагонали, равны нулю, а каждый элемент, не принадлежащий
главной диагонали, равен 2, 1 или 0 (числу очков, набранных в игре: 2 –выигрыш, 1 –ничья, 0 –проигрыш). Найти число команд, имеющих больше побед, чем поражений и определить номера команд, прошедших чемпионат без поражений.

На данный момент у меня имеется вот такая часть кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int N = 0, i, j;
    cout << "Введите количество команд: ";
    cin >> N;
    srand(time(0));
    int m[66][66];
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            m[i][j] = rand() % 3;
                if (i == j) m[i][j] = 0;                //Просталение нулей на главной диагонали.
                else if (m[i][j] == 0) m[j][i] == 2;    //Условие для того,чтобы матрица не была симметричной.
                else m[j][i] = m[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    //Вывод матрицы
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            cout << m[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    _getch();
}
```

Условие,которое я сделала для того, чтобы у одной команды отражалась победа, а у другой проигрыш не работает. Не знаю, как это реализовать.
+Пока не могу додуматься как найти число команд, у которых побед больше,чем поражений и как определить номера команд, прошедших чемпионат без поражений.

Буду очень благодарна знающим людям,которые смогут помочь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

#include <time.h>

#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int N = 0, i, j;

    cout << "Введите количество команд: ";

    cin >> N;

    srand(time(0));

    int m[66][66];

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)

    {

        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)

        {

            m[i][j] = rand() % 3;

            if (i == j) m[i][j] = 0;

            else if (m[i][j] == 0) m[j][i] = 2;

            else if (m[i][j] == 2) m[j][i] = 0;

            else if (m[i][j] == 1) m[j][i] = 1;

            else m[j][i] = m[i][j];

        }

    }


    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)

    {

        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)

        {

            cout << m[i][j] << ' ';

        }

        cout << endl;

    }

    int v = 2;

    int v2 = N;

    int** arr2 = new int* [v];

    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++)

    {

        *(arr2 + i) = new int[v2];

    }

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)

    {

        for (int j = 0; j < v2; j++)

        {

            count++;

            arr2[i][j] = count;

        }

    }

    int points = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)

    {

        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)

        {

            if (m[i][j] == 2)

            {

                points++;

            }

        }

        arr2[1][i] = points;

        points = 0;

        cout << endl;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++)

    {

        for (int j = 0; j < v2; j++)

        {

            cout << arr2[i][j] << " ";

        }

        cout << endl;

    }

    int A = 0;
    int nextv = 0;
    int team = 0;
    int max = A - 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < v; i++)
    {
        max = A - 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < v2; j++)
        {
            if (max < (nextv = arr2[i][j]))
            {
                max = nextv;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < v; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < v2; j++)
        {
            if (arr2[i][j] == max)
            {
                cout << "Команда №" << arr2[0][j] << " набрали наибольшее кол-во побед" << endl;
            }
        }
    }


    int points2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (m[i][j] == 0)
            {
                points2++;
            }
        }
        arr2[1][i] = points2-1;
        points2 = 0;
        cout << endl;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < v2; j++)

        {
            cout << arr2[i][j] << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    int fail = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < v; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < v2; j++)
        {
            if (arr2[i][j] == 0)
            {
                fail++;
                cout << "Команда №" << arr2[0][j] << " прошла чемпионал без поражений" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    if (fail == 0)
    {
        cout << "Ни одна команда не прошла чемпионат без поражений" << endl;
    }
    

    _getch();

}
```